# How should I compile a .lib in release mode using vs 2010 C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compilation, compiler-errors

Here is the error when I compile alglib.What should i do?
Is it okay that i use vs 2012 to compile the source code to .lib in release mode?
note: vs2010, C++, release mode, to get .lib 
.............................................................
I have a library, all in which are .h and .cpp. To speed up the compilition of my whole project, I want to make them a .lib. According to the answers below, I have no choice but to compile a dll if i want to speed up and do not want to use vs 2012 for all my work?

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during BuildLibrary
1>  
1>    Version 10.00.30319.01
1>  
1>    ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>    ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>    ExceptionAddress         = 6C8E2803 (6C700000)
"F:\VS2010\VC\bin\c2.dll"
1>    NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>    ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000 
1>    ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 014005CA
1>  
1>  CONTEXT:
1>    Eax    = 00000025  Esp    = 0105D44C
1>    Ebx    = 0105D50C  Ebp    = 0105D464
1>    Ecx    = 014005CA  Esi    = 6C96D3A2
1>    Edx    = 6B55CC48  Edi    = 6C9635FC
1>    Eip    = 6C8E2803  EFlags = 00010206
1>    SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
1>    SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
1>    SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
1>    Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>    Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>    Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
```

Comment: That is an error internal to the linker, a bug, you should probably be reporting it to Microsoft together with the code to reproduce the error and as much other information as you can.

Comment: Compiler error actually. No need to report, your VS version is too old. A possible workaround is Project + Properties, General, Whole Program Optimization = No.  Rebuild everything, including libraries.

Comment: Is it okay that i use vs 2012 to compile the source code to .lib in release mode?

Comment: If you are compiling a static library, then you should be using the same compiler version as the 'consumers' of your static library (i.e. if you expect people to use VS 2010 with your library, you need to provide a VS 2010 version of it). If you are compiling a DLL, this is less of an issue as it is possible to 'mix' compiler version in that case.

Comment: Are you using VS 2010 RTM or VS 2010 Service Pack 1?